# Download offline web page and view on iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, internet, web-browser

I need to be able to download an off-line webpage and view it on an iPad. I must be able to access it without being connected to the internet, any browser will work, preferably Chrome though. Is this possible?

I've created a page with a test example:

`<a href="http://www.website.com/file_test2.html" download="test_file.html">Click Here To Download test webpage</a>`

but clicking the link seems to only open the webpage and not download it. It works fine on a laptop or tower (something not using an application, or with an accessible file tree).

I've also tried viewing the site an offline reader, but they won't seem to load it. I think there is too much jQuery for it to work. The reason for all of this is so people can view the website in places without an internet connection (cabins, camping, basements, anywhere else without internet access).

Comment: Reading list was meant to do this - have you ruled that function out to cache your particular website?

Comment: I'm not sure what Reading List is. The browser would have to download the actual html of given webpage(s), and be able to open them without an internet connection. There is a typical `<a href>` link to download the page/folder. Can Reading List download something and then open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with Safari's reading list feature:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TI39

It is built into the OS but doesn't integrate well with the Chrome app as you asked. You also might need to do some code changes to have all the features you desire work in offline mode, but since web apps were the first iOS app Apple created, there is lots of documentation at https://developer.apple.com/Safari

The iOS version of Opera has a save for offline option.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but I think it's the closest option.